# WP: get value from add_action with global variable, singleton variable

Tags: php, wordpress

can anyone explain why I do not see my changes in the global variable?

```
global $globalVar; 

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'some_scripts') ;

function some_scripts()
{
    global $wp_scripts, $globalVar;

    $globalVar = 123;
}

var_dump($globalVar);
```

In my global variable i get NULL! Why?

I tried to use the classes but nothing happened. Always NULL. For example:

```
class SingletonTest
{
    public $a;
    protected static $_instance;

    private function __clone() {}
    public static function getInstance() {

        if (null === self::$_instance) {

            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'some_scripts') ;

function some_scripts() {

    $a = SingletonTest::getInstance();
    $a->a = 123;
}

$b = SingletonTest::getInstance();
var_dump($b);
```

Get next:

> object(SingletonTest)#220 (1) { ["a"]=> NULL }

Comment: Because you are using `wp_print_scripts` hook, so this hook will call in your `head` when page is rendering...

Try `init` hook instead of `wp_print_scripts`...
Hope its work...

Comment: Thanks, but i need to get it with this hook information. This hook works and administration of the site. The question is why in the instance of the class is not written information ?

Comment: print your global variable in footer section...because this file is including in init process and hook will be call after that so you cant see effect before calling your function...

Comment: `add_action` is used to hook your function to particular action, not for `calling` your function at place of define...